# how to implement a type file in symfony2

Tags: symfony

The problem is to handle the file type fields.

By doing this I take the field as "Browse to upload the file" now to save time remains. I do not know how to handle it properly if anyone has an example. would be very useful.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you have and what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

The cookbook has a nice tutorial

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Plus more basics in the reference

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/file.html

Comment: I did implement a file upload using uploadify which is more user friendly and Ajax ready. Have a look to the Genemu bundle